# EWS SyncFolderItems - Delete appointments on client-database

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am working on a sync client that replicate appointment from and to EWS (Office 365).

In general I am following the documentation provided by MS:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/office/dn440952(v=exchg.150).aspx

My problem:
This article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/office/dn605828(v=exchg.150).aspx#Arbeiten%20mit%20Bezeichnern shows that the `ItemId` of a appointment may change and is **not unique**.

So investigating I found out that people load `cleanGlobalObjectId` from appointment that is unique once and for all.

```
// unique id for sync that do not change like item id
var cleanGlobalObjectId = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Meeting, 0x23, MapiPropertyType.Binary);
var psPropSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties) { cleanGlobalObjectId };
```

So I use

```
var appointment = Appointment.Bind(service, item, psPropSet);
object calIdVal;
appointment.TryGetProperty(cleanGlobalObjectId, out calIdVal);
var syncId = Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])calIdVal);
```

`syncId` is so far I tested unique and works for INSERT and UPDATE appointments into my database.

When I now use `SyncFolderItems` from EWS I get a collection of items for `create`,`update`,`delete`.

**My problem:**

I can not load appointments with `Appointment.Bind()` that are deleted.
But I need to load the appointment to get my `syncId`.

The `SyncFolderItems` collection let me access `ItemId.UniqueKey` and `ItemId.ChangeKey`.

So if an appointment is moved or deleted in a users calendar I have no chance to identify the correct record in my client database where I save the replicated appointments.

So anyone have some advise or any other approaches? If I forgot to add some details please also provide some feedback so I can add this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save both, the cleanGlobalObjectId as well as the ItemId in your database. This way, you can tackle the removal of an item as well as the event that Exchange recreates your appointment (which doesn't happen all the time, just under certain circumstances).

Comment: Thanks Henning, I was just going this way to save both and in delete case use the ItemId to delete the appointment. Each Sync update the ItemId as well so I can be sure that my Itemid is up to date in a delete case.